# Create a json file from other json files

Tags: json, angular

I have 2 json files:

User.json:

```
    {
         "users": [
           {
              "username": "User1",
              "app": "Git",
              "role": "Manager"
           },
           {
              "username": "user2",
              "app": "Git",
              "role": "Developer"
           }
          ]
 }
```

App.js:

```
{
     "apps": [
       {
          "appName": "Git",
          "repo": "http://repo1..."
       },
       {
          "appName": "Jenkins",
          "repo": "htpp://repo2..."
       }
      ]
    }
```

I'm working on an Angular-CLI apllication for the first time and I want to generate a new json file called infos.json containing the content of the 2 files (User.json + App.json) without redundancy.

Expected file: 
Infos.json:

```
{
         "infos": [
           {
              "username": "User1",
              "appName": "GIT",
              "role": "Manager",
              "repo": "http://repo1..."
           },
           {
             "username": "User2",
             "appName": "Jenkins",
             "role": "Developer",
             "repo": "htpp://repo2..."
           }
          ]
        }
```

How can I do it in my Angular-CLI app ?

Comment: angular cli dont do that kind of task ...you need to code for it

Comment: you have this web pack plugin check this merge-jsons-webpack-plugin https://github.com/tettusud/merge-jsons-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating task in task runner. Some of the task runner are Grunt, gulp etc. 
Grunt and gulp have different inbuilt packages.

Grunt:  npm i [grunt-merge-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge-json)

Gulp: npm [i gulp-merge-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge-json)

If you are using web-pack so there is a inbuilt package called [merge-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge-json)

Comment: Thank you, I did it with gulp-merge-json :)

Comment: @Develo55 That's great. Happy coding !